# How to make a realistic 2D player movement (jump, fluidity...)

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, game-physics, physics

How could I make a player move in 2D, make it jump, with fluidity of movement (a progressive acceleration, fluid jump)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to read [pygame - Sprite Module Introduction](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html). A lot of resources and projects can be found on [pygame - tutorials — wiki](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/tutorials#Pygame%20Tutorials%20on%20Specific%20Topics) and [pygame - projects](https://www.pygame.org/tags/all).

I particularly recommend you for your project [Pygame Platformer Tutorial](https://coderslegacy.com/python/pygame-platformer-game-development/).

The code can be simplified a lot by the use of [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) and [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2):

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite): 
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__() 
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y)
        self.move = pygame.math.Vector2()
        try:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('image.png')
        except:
            self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
            self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))

    def update(self):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[K_LEFT]:
            self.move.x -= 50
        if pressed[K_RIGHT]:
            self.move.x += 50
        if pressed[K_UP]:
            self.move.y = -1000

        self.pos = self.pos + self.move * time_passed
        self.move.x *= 0.8 # slow down (decrease progressively)
        self.move.y += 5000 * time_passed

        if self.pos.y > 600:
            self.pos.y = 600

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
            self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
        if self.rect.right > 800:
            self.rect.right = 800
            self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx

player = Player(400, 600)
allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    time_passed = clock.tick(60) / 1000
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    allSprites.update()

    screen.fill((220, 220, 255))
    allSprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thank you ! It lights me up like 800 * 600 pixels...